Django Grappelli Custom Dashboard not showing App Models
Django 5.0.1 & Grappelli v4.01
Have a site running on a local runserver host and the custom dashboard works as expected. The site has been pushed to Azure as an App Service. The custom dashboard only shows the groups, Sites and Users Models from auth.
I am logging in as a superuser in both cases and both the local runserver and app service instances are pointed to the same backend database on Azure.
I suspect permissions but not sure why the core models appear but the app based ones don't on the App Service.
What am I missing? thanks in advance.
